# Ideal Boot partition for 1Tb hard drive to install ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, lenovo

Can Anybody please tell me the ideal hard drive partitioning for Ubuntu 18.04?
I  want to run Linux in my laptop without dual boot.
My computer specifications are

```
8th Gen Intel Core i5-8250U
```

```
NVIDIA GEFORCE MX150 (2G GDDR5) graphics
```

```
1 TB HDD
```

```
ram-8 GB
```

Comment: The ideal is still user preference.  You can use swapfiles instead of swap (so swap partition is optional) and the default installation is /home on the main partition (*I prefer a seperate /home mostly as I feel safe should I need to re-install, or want to use the system without mounting my /home [which is rare]*). So a single partition is okay. It depends on how you want to use it in the future....

Comment: Ubuntu has automatic hard drive partition as part of its installer which will use appropriate defaults for a target drive, or free space on a drive. Was there any specific requirements for this install?

Comment: I just need better performance without slowing up during boot.

Comment: Partition ideas will not help you,  will need to boot and then see if anything is slowing it down, and then fix that.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you seem to want a faster boot, not an "ideal" HDD partitioning scheme.

Comment: For faster booting, the ideal partitioning is ESP, / (root) & /home on SSD, but all data normally in /home on HDD. Since /home's hidden settings are tiny you can keep those in / (root).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no.  There is no idea partition.  Some like to have just a /(root) partition for everything, some like / and /home partitions.  Some people are happy with just 30gb, some think 1TB is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have minimal ssd.
If you have at least 30 gb ssd, Best you install on ssd and keep swap partition on hdd.

Assuming you have no ssd and only hdd.
Allot 100 gb for root. Create /home partition with more space like 200 gb.
If in future, you have to remove ubuntu or upgrade, you may use your /home if its separate partition.
If you want to create backup then also having two separate partitions /home and / will help.